# Brightness control keys don't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, brightness, search, function-keys

Pressing brightness increase button opens the search bar which used to open after pressing ctrl+F in Ubuntu 20.04. Brightness decrease key does not work. I am controlling brightness from the settings. Buttons were working perfectly before. Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things,

1. Update your system with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
2. check if the `brightness control key` are recognized `xev -event keyboard` then press your brightness key, if event are generated it mean the keys are recognized, so it is not that
3. Install `brightness-controller` from the `Ubuntu Software Center` with this software you can control the brightness directly